# Why Jdk DateFormat use StringBuffer instead of StringBuilder?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I checked Jdk19 source code and I noticed that DateFormat always uses StringBuffer when formatting a Date into String. Shouldn't that be StringBuilder because it's faster?

Comment: `DateFormat` is an old class and may well predate `StringBuilder` (added in jdk1.5). The newer `DateTimeFormatter` (which you should use) does use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Not what you asked, I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead as @TiiJ7 said use `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because at the time when `DateFormat` was written (Java 1.1) there was no class `StringBuilder` (which only exists since Java 1.5).

If the `StringBuffer` was an implementation detail this would be no problem.

But `DateFormat` has two methods that accept and return a `StringBuffer`:

- [`format(Object obj, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition fieldPosition)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.lang.Object,java.lang.StringBuffer,java.text.FieldPosition))
- [`format(Date date, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition fieldPosition)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date,java.lang.StringBuffer,java.text.FieldPosition))

Rewriting these methods to accept and return a `StringBuilder` would break existing code.

---

Please note that (as Johannes Kuhn has pointed out) the first of these two methods is specified by the abstract base class `java.text.Format` (also from Java 1.1), so changing this would have even greater implications.

Comment: Wow, specified by [java.text.Format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Format.html). That looks like a very old interface.